# What is first? ARP vs ICMP

Tags: arp, ping, icmp

I want to know what is first after STP.

There are just three devices, switch and two hosts.
A switch is not configurated and two hosts have each IP by static.
Of course, two hosts are connected to the switch

From here, 
A host is going to ping to B host.
At the time, what is first between ARP and ICMP?
Will A host ping after ARP or omit ARP?.....

Thanks
Terry

Comment: If someone has provided an answer that resolves your question, please consider marking it as the accepted answer. This will reward both the person who provided the answer and yourself with additional reputation. If you do not do so, your question will periodically get refreshed back to the main page, possibly distracting community members from other questions they may be able to help answer for other users. Thank you.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 9):

**Short Answer**: The answer is that it depends.

**Longer Explanation**: Naturally, when a device is sending out unicast IP traffic, it needs to add the layer 2 headers (including destination MAC address) to the frame before sending it on the wire. This IP-to-MAC mapping is exactly what the ARP process is there to provide to the host.

Based on this statement, one might think that this naturally means that ARP traffic will automatically be sent before any ICMP traffic. However, once a host learns this IP-to-MAC mapping, it inserts it into an ARP table for some period of time. So a host will check this ARP table for such a mapping first and only send out ARP if there is no entry.

So in your example, let's say that *Host A* has no entry for *Host B*'s IP address in the ARP table. When *Host A* pings *Host B* the traffic exchange is like this:

```
 Host A              Host B
 ARP_Request  ---> 
              <---   ARP_Reply
 ICMP_Echo    ---> 
              <---   ICMP_Echo_Reply
```

Now let's say that *Host A* does have an entry for *Host B*'s IP address in the ARP table. When *Host A* pings *Host B* the traffic exchange is instead like this:

```
 Host A              Host B
 ICMP_Echo    ---> 
              <---   ICMP_Echo_Reply
```

So to answer your specific question.

> Will A host ping after ARP or omit ARP?

*Host A* will either send the ICMP after ARP or omit ARP depending on the status of the entry for *Host B* in it's ARP table.